# IBM FileNet Content Manager Upgrade 4.5 to 5.2

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet

We are upgrading IBM Filenet Content Manager 4.5.1.

what version of Filenet and distribution  recommended install.  Is it the IBM filnet content manager version 5.1 or 5.2, based on stability ?

I am bit concerned beacuse of so many customizations and workflows running on our existing 4.5.1 system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend going to FileNet Content Platform Engine 5.2. I've recently completed an upgrade from 4.5 to 5.2, and no changes to any existing workflows or client code were required. There have been some additions to the API, but no breaking changes.

The latest fix pack, released a few weeks ago, is 5.2.0.3. I can't think of any advantage to going to 5.1 instead of 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with cmaitchison. We have recently completed a 5.2 upgrade an it is straightforward. Even though the previous custom applications would work, it is better to re-compile using the latest libraries and the version of JRE your application server would use.